# Array indirection issue

Tags: c, arrays, indirection

I have an issue with array indirections in C. Let's declare an array :

```
int tab[3];
```

How can these three variable display the same result ? It looks like the memory cell of the tab contains the adress itself AND the first value. I don't understand.

```
tab
&tab
&tab[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays like `int tab[3]` decay to a pointer to the first element when `tab` is used in a context where a pointer is expected. `&tab[0]` is - obviously - the address of the first element, too.

Similar but a bit different is `&tab`, since this is actually a pointer of type `int (*)[3]`, i.e. it points to an array of ints of size 3. The address is still the same as that of the first element in `tab`; yet you may observe differences incrementing such a pointer, and you may get warnings when assigning like `int* x = &tab`.